# Docker container won't run 32 bit iperf executable copied with wget

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-14.04

Though iperf is successfully installed inside the container, Docker doesn't recognize it:

Docker version:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client version: 1.0.1
Client API version: 1.12
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 990021a
Server version: 1.0.1
Server API version: 1.12
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Git commit (server): 990021a
```

Image inf.

```
root@15cb22522f30:/#uname -a && cat /etc/lsb-release 
Linux f93f33213b2a 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"
```

iperf package installation:

```
root@15cb22522f30:/#wget https://iperf.fr/download/iperf_2.0.2/iperf_2.0.2-4_i386
root@15cb22522f30:/#chmod +x iperf_2.0.2-4_i386
root@15cb22522f30:/#sudo mv iperf_2.0.2-4_i386 /usr/bin/iperf
```

File located:

```
root@15cb22522f30:/# which iperf
/usr/bin/iperf
```

---

**Docker doesn't recognize it:**

```
root@15cb22522f30:/# iperf
bash: /usr/bin/iperf: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit system.

Docker runs on 64 bit systems, and produces 64 bit containers [*]

The copied iperf file is a 32 bit binary.

```
file /usr/bin/iperf
/usr/bin/iperf: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
```

After hunting around, I found if you install these 32 bit libs in the docker container:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libc-i386 lib32stdc++6
```

Then it will at least load iperf:

```
iperf
Usage: iperf [-s|-c host] [options]
Try `iperf --help' for more information.
```

[*] A few people have hacked dockers tools to run on 32 bit systems, so it can be done -- but it isn't the norm and appears to have been rejected by the docker leaders in favor of a single standard.

Answer (score 1):

Paul's answer solved the issue. I additionally had to [install i386 architecture for 32-bit packages to be installed automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551840/unable-to-locate-package-libc6-dbgi386-in-docker):

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6-dbg
apt-get install libc6-dbg:i386
apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```